# suddenly serifs in math mode

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif

I have a problem since recently. When typesetting math, a new font is used, and I have no idea why. While usually, the variables look like this,
`$\lambda, \mathcal{X}, x, \sum$`, i.e. without serifs on the Lambda, a more "round" `$x$` etc., they suddenly look like this:

[image: The wrong style]

The only thing I did in recent time is to add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

in the preamble (was necessary to use Umlaute in the bibliography). 
I read that using `\usepackage{mathsf}` could help - but I never used this package before, so why would I need it now? I'd like to go back to where I've been instead of installing yet another package (furthermore, the automatic installing of this does not work; it says `mathsf.sty` not found, but that is another issue).

I will try to give a MWE - can I attach files here? I'm posting my source code here (it seems not too minimal, but I felt the need to include all the loaded packages to ensure that you get all info). The reason why I post this even though there are many topics on the same question is that I need to find out why this suddenly changed (that, or I'm going crazy).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

The broad field of robust optimization ...
\begin{alignat}{5}
\min_{x\in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathfrak{R}^n} & x^TQx |\mu^Tx \geq R \\
\max_{x\in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathfrak{R}^n} & \mu^Tx-\lambda x^TQx\\     
\mathcal{X}=\left\{x\in\mathfrak{R}^n|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1, x_i\geq0,\lambda\right\}
\end{alignat}
ensures that short-sales are not allowed and the sum of all the asset weights is 1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Marie, I tried to boil down your example a bit but it is still far from minimal, e.g. here [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) . The code sample is automatically formatted if you add spaces in front of every line. Maybe you can narrow it down a bit further by removing all packages that do not have any influence on your problem.

Comment: The font change is mostly caused by the `pslatex` package.

Comment: The change is probably caused by `pslatex`. That package is considered obsolete, see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pslatex . Better try `newtx` or something like that.

Comment: okay, I used newtx and it looks awesome, great! Now I did some research and read that newtxmath should be used with newtxtext; this does not work for me though, "fatal error, pdf could not be created".

Are any of the following math-packages redundant and can be taken out?

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}

Comment: It is enough to load `\usepackage{mathtools}`. It loads `amsmath` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

[To remove from the unanswered list]

The problem here is caused by the obsolete `pslatex` package: using for example `newtxmath`/`newtxtext` should solve the issue and generally improve the glyphs used.